# Typo3 (8.7.30, composer) Extension Manager not showing up in backend

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I have a composer typo3 (8.7.30) project, but somehow the extension-manager does not show up.

I tried the following:

- `./vendor/bin/typo3 extensionmanager:extension:install extensionmanager`
- `./vendor/bin/typo3cms extension:activate extensionmanager`
- `./vendor/bin/typo3cms extension:setup extensionmanager`

My user has admin rights and I can see other admin tools. I also tried to create a new admin with the install tool and the new user had the same "problem".

Other modules - including custom ones - are showing up.

Any ideas on how to tackle this?

Edit: When I install the project step by step without generating the package state it's working fine, but the moment I generate package states the extension manager is missing - even though the entry in the PackageStates.php

Comment: can you show your composer.json?

Comment: Sure: [here you go](https://gist.github.com/graseggergh/3c8be96280de89b2762caea04fc4b2b8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One userTsConfig.ts disabled the module in the production context. I didn't check for it because the behavior was new for me. It was neither a typo3 or composer problem, just a configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

After installing from your `composer.json`, the extension manager is available.

I guess that your `PackageStates.php` just somehow misses the extensionmanager:

```
    'extensionmanager' => [
        'packagePath' => 'typo3/sysext/extensionmanager/',
    ],
```

If I manually remove that section, `vendor/bin/typo3cms install:generatepackagestates` (from the package `helhum/typo3-console` which you already have installed) would regenerate it.

Comment: Sadly that didn't fix it.

Edit: It's not a fresh project but an update I am working on.